# Let $F$ be a field and $f: \mathbb{Z} \to F$ be a ring epimorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, epimorphisms

Here we have $F$ a field and $f: \mathbb{Z} \to F$ a ring epimorphism. We are to prove that $F$ is a finite field with non-zero characteristic.

I know that since $f$ is an epimorphism, we have that $\forall x\in F$, $\exists y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x) = y$. (As an epimorphism is a surjective ring homomorphism).

I am unsure about two things: Am I to prove that F is finite, or just prove that it has a non-zero characteristic. Either way, I could use some guidance. Thank you :)

PS This is for HW, so I only require a good hint about how to approach the problem.

Comment: Proving that $F$ is finite amounts to proving that $F$ has non-zero characteristic.

Comment: @walkar, not really. There *are* infinite fields of positive characteristic!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez But no finite fields of zero characteristic, as I stated. They are not equivalent, but all finite fields have nonzero characteristic.

Comment: Note that “ring epimorphism” might *not* mean “surjective”: epimorphisms in the category of rings are not necessarily surjective.

Comment: @egreg it better should be surjective for that exercise though.

Comment: @quid Of course; I was just pointing out to a terminology problem. Usually I avoid “epimorphism” for this reason: it's shorter than “surjective homomorphism”, but it can be ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $F$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/ \ker f$.

---

On your particular request: since you are asked to show that $F$ is a finite field you must show this. The characteristic is then always finite. The converse is not true though. Consider the quotient field of the polynomial ring over a finite field as example.

Comment: ...and check somehow that the kernel is not zero.

Comment: So to prove this, I need to show that $ker(f)$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, the $im(f)$ is a subring of $F$, and $im(f)$ is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{Z}/ker(f)$? 

I think we get the last one for free.

Comment: You might know as isomorphism theorem or something like this, that for any homomorphism of rings $f : R \to R'$ we have $R/\ker f  $ is isomorphic to $im f$. This could save some effort.

Comment: Is there an easy way to show the kernel is not zero? I'm having difficulties doing this.

Comment: @Calculus08 if there kernel were zero than the field would be isomorphic to the ring of integers, which is  not a field.